# "Edit plan settings" opens every time I press enter

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Every time I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, a Control Panel window opens to the *Edit Plan Settings* menu. For reference, I am running Windows 7 (64 bit).

**Why is the Power Options menu opening every time I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?**

[image: Power management options]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You most likely opened the **Windows Mobility Center** on accident with <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will open the **Power Options** menu while the Mobility Center window is focused. The key should function normally after closing the window.

[image: Windows Mobility Center]

- *Source: [Microsoft Community Forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-update/edit-plan-settings-opens-every-time-i-click-enter/62ce1c5f-a3ea-4eac-b327-ca94158c199f)*

To clarify, pressing <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> will only open the Mobility Center on Windows 7. The shortcut was changed in Windows 8 and 10 to open the [Power User Menu](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-the-power-user-menu-2625968) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If using a different keyboard (or on-screen keyboard doesn't work, and Windows Key + X doesn't work, nothing works, then try this:

**Open task manager (CTRL + ALT + DEL) then find 'explorer.exe', click on it, and click restart.**

This fixed it for me without having to restart my computer or system restore.